# I want input to be available in all methods, how do I declare it?

Tags: java

So what I'm trying to do is have my main method where I call other methods into it to process various bits of user input code.

Rather than writing System.in every time, I want to define input outside everything and the whole class will recognise what that means.

This is what I have:

```
public static final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

But it doesn't seem to work as intended and my program falls apart as soon as I pull the next method into the main method. I've been researching this but I don't understand the answers in relation to what I'm attempting to do.

Can anyone help?

As requested, here's the exception I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at question1project.TeleSurvey.ageInput(TeleSurvey.java:83)
    at question1project.TeleSurvey.main(TeleSurvey.java:38)
```

And the line in my code it's throwing the exception at:

```
a = input.nextInt();
```

Comment: Please define falls apart.

Comment: The build stops and throws an exception at me where it first calls the input

Comment: Then please post the exception in your question.

Comment: I've added the exception and where it's throwing it.

Comment: The question doesn;t seem to be related to the exception. Your problem is you've asked the program to retrieve an integer from the user (`nextInt()`) but whatever you have entered (either at the console or from a file) is not an integer.  That is what the exception is saying.  You should read the Javadoc for that exception.

Comment: "as I pull the next method into the main method" : methods should not go into main().  Pleaes post an [MCVE]

Comment: I’m guessing from you stacktrace, it seems your program is trying to read an age as an integer (sounds reasonable) and doesn’t encounter an integer in the input. Possible reasons include (1) the Scanner has read farther or less far in the input than you expect (2) the age entered as something that doesn’t fulfil the requirements for integers (including letter o, l, I instead of digits 0 and 1, but this sounds unlikely for an age except from 10 to 19).

Answer (score 0):

You're calling [Scanner.nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) as the documentation says, if the next input is not an integer literal then it will throw `InputMismatchException`.

You should check the input if it's an integer, if you're not expecting input to be integer then you should use the appropriate method of `Scanner`.

For sharing the input among classes, you can assign it to a `public static` variable of a class.